# Any open source Android Image Gallery SDKs?

Tags: android

I've been wondering if there are any open source SDKs for creating image gallery type functionality for an Android app.  I essentially am looking for something simple that would run much like the native android gallery app.  I have an Activity with a GridView that displays some thumbnails.  I then want the user to select an image, and launch into a Gallery type Activity where the user can scroll between photos, pinch/zoom, etc...

I'm fairly comfortable rolling my own code to do this, but figured that if there's some standard package or SDK out there that does something like this already, no need to waste my time re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are asking for is not available for android.

Answer (score 3):

Android has a default gallery view. [Here the example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html).

This seems to be a [coverflow](https://github.com/robotmedia/Android-3D-Gallery/tree/master/AndroidCoverFlow) gallery found from github